# Are all functions $\sum \sin (x - a)$ translates of $\sin x$?

Tags: trigonometry

I am having a momentary lapse.  I was plotting random functions of the type:

$$  f(\theta) = \sum e^{i(\theta - \theta_i)} $$

where $\theta_i$ were random numbers.  To my surprise and embarassment these all looked like translated sine functions with various amplitudes.  In fact

$$ \sum e^{i(\theta - \theta_i)}  = e^{i\theta} \sum e^{- i \theta_i}
= \sum e^{- i \theta_i} \big(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta \big)
$$

If I take only the imaginary parts I obtain:

$$ \sum \sin (\theta - \theta_i ) = \big(\sum \sin  \theta_i \big) \cos \theta  
+ \big(\sum \cos  \theta_i \big) \sin \theta  $$

I guess what remains to show that we have obtained a translate of sine:

$$ A \cos \theta + B \sin \theta = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2} \;\bigg( \frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2 + B^2}} \,\cos \theta +  
\frac{B}{\sqrt{A^2 + B^2}}\, \sin \theta \bigg)  $$

and I suppose that is the arc-tangent of sum angle, 
$$ \phi = \tan^{-1} \tfrac{B}{A}  $$

and we'd have by the sum of angles formula:

$$ A \cos \theta + B \sin \theta = \sin \left(\theta + \tan^{-1}\tfrac{B}{A}\right) $$

---

My question is:  $$f(\theta) \stackrel{?}{=} C \sin (\theta - \theta_0)$$

Comment: It's a little unclear to me what exactly you're asking

Answer (score 1):

Yes, every sum of translated sines (i.e., every two functions of the form $A\sin (\theta + c)$, for constants $A$ and $c$) is in fact a multiple of a single translated sine function.

The proof is inductive: once you show it for two, you can then show it for 3, 4, etc.

Your reasoning shows it just fine for two functions (although there's a little work still to do, as you note).

There's a small subtlety: when you sum two displaced sines, you *might* get the everywhere-zero function, which is indeed a multiple of sine, but not a very interesting one.

To make your argument simpler, it helps to know that 
$$
\sin x = \frac{1}{2} \left( e^{ix} - e^{-ix} \right)
$$

By the way, your last formula is missing a constant factor on the right-hand sideL your sum of $A \cos \theta + B \sin \theta$ should be $C \sin (\ldots )$, and you're missing the $C$. That same factor is missing from your final "question-equality" as well.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $f''(\theta) = - f(\theta)$.  The only solutions are $$f(\theta) = A \sin \theta + B \cos \theta = C \sin (\theta - \theta_0)$$  In fact $C = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2}$.  Even though you started with $n$ terms, it reduces to a single term.  It's a matter of luck.